# How to resolve javax/mail/MessagingException?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am using eclipse indigo to run my tomcat server, when I am launching tomcat server, the tomcat server successfully up and running, but with error shown in the console.

```
ERROR  - ContextLoader[177]: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Error registering bean with name 'com.huahsin68.MyBoc' defined in class path resource [my-spring.xml]: Class that bean class [com.huahsin68.MyBocImp] depends on not found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
```

It seems like the MessagingException wasn't found. I have check in the Java Build Path > Libraries, I notice that javax.mail_1.4.0.v200105080615.jar was there. This jar file is locate under eclipse > plugins folder. Is there anything solution to rectify this problem?

THanks @!

Answer (score 20):

With Maven, you can add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Current version is 1.5.6. Also groupId and artifactId changed (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020533/javamail-api-from-maven. Now you should use     
      "<groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.6</version>"
. You can also check it here: https://maven.java.net/#nexus-search;gav~com.sun.mail~javax.mail~~~~kw,versionexpand.

Answer (score 11):

Try the following:

1. Download the java mail jars from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html
2. Add the jars to your WEB-INF/lib folder
3. Add the jars to Java Build Path > Libraries

That should do it.

Comment: I have did a search in Maven directory and found out there is a mail.jar. It seems like the eclipse not able to resolve the link.

Answer (score 7):

For gradle/android users, in `build.gradle (Module app)`:

```
compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.1'
```

Comment: this is best solution. No manual downloads needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, running tomcat stand-alone (that is, not through Eclipse).  I copied mail-1.4.jar to my tomcat/lib directory.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those conning late in this ..
I got the same error resolved by adding below jar.
geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.3.jar