# The import javax.mail cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

```
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.SendFailedException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;    

private void sendMail() throws MessagingException{

    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String password = "abcde12345";
    String from = "testing@gmail.com";
    String toAddress = email;
    String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/jam.jpg";

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtps.auth", true);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
    message.setSubject("Anti-Theft Attachment");

    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText(smsMessageString);

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    message.setContent(multipart);

    try{
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect(host, from, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        System.out.println("Mail Sent Successfully");
        transport.close();
    } catch (SendFailedException sfe){
        System.out.println(sfe);
    }
};
```

I am developing an application which the application will automatically send out an email to user informing user the current phone status once the phone is stolen or lost. But I faced problem in importing javax.mail "The import javax.mail cannot be resolved". What should I do? Thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Comment: ADD 3 jars found in the following link to your Android Project. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/375953

Answer (score 12):

Try add this [javax.mail.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/javamail-138606.html)
.You can download it [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home)
,hope this will help.
There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743031/how-to-resolve-javax-mail-messagingexception).