# JavaMail API from Maven

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail

I am trying to upgrade to latest Java Mail utility.

From

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

to (my Intention)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But I don't find 1.5.1 for mail artifact,

but I can see

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My Question is why group id changed and if I change the group id for 1.5.1 do I need to change all my mail implementation that is already present (package name change and any other stuff) and what is the difference between `com.sun.mail` vs `javax.mail`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The Maven coordinates changed some time ago to be compatible with the scheme described [here](https://glassfish.java.net/wiki-archive/Maven%20Versioning%20Rules.html).  The new coordinates are [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

In short:

- The groupId `javax.mail` is no longer used for the implementation.
- There is a new artifact at `javax.mail:javax.mail-api`. It provides the `javax.mail-api.jar` file. This contains the JavaMail API definitions only, suitable for compiling against.
- `com.sun.mail:javax.mail` contains the `javax.mail.jar` file, the JavaMail reference implementation jar file, including the SMTP, IMAP, and POP3 protocol providers.

So, you should either use `com.sun.mail:javax.mail` for compilation and packaging/deploy, or use `javax.mail:javax.mail-api` for compilation and then deploy the `com.sun.mail:javax.mail` jar where appropriate (e.g., your Tomcat lib).

Comment: If you follow the [link above](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.2_Release), you'll see that the javax.mail groupId has only one artifactId - javax.mail-api, but that artifact is only good for compiling your programs, it's not good for running your programs.  If you want to run your programs, you need the com.sun.mail groupId with artifactId javax.mail.

Comment: So good! I was searching for the implementation but google and maven would only point me to javax.mail apis...

Comment: In this link it indeed say so, but if you search in Google (for me it was the first search result) you can also find this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4 and you point it to javaxmail / mail artifact, which in fact also works.

Comment: That's a very old version; don't use it.

Comment: I've been using javax.mail:javax.mail-api (AAARGH) and searching all the source code for "starttls.enable" and found nothing. So your answer explains the last hour of misery I've been through. Even Google let's you down these days.