# Fail to send mail , Connect timeout error

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a mail sending function using java mail API. It is working in local environment. But when i deploy on aws instance ,it is throwing error. At first I thought the connection from aws instance to mail server was not allowed.But from the aws instance, it can telent to the mail server with port 587. I tried to increase timeout option also and still the same exception ,socket timeout exception . Please help me to correct if my configuration is wrong.

Here's the dependency that i used .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's the mail configuration.

```
public static boolean sendMail() {

        Properties props = getSMTPProperties(HOST);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(SENDER, PWD);
            }
        });

        try {
            Message message = createMessage(session, SENDER_EMAIL, RECEIVER, "testing", "testing");
            Transport.send(message);

            Store store = session.getStore("imap");
            store.connect(HOST, SENDER, PWD);
            Folder folder = store.getFolder("Sent Items");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            folder.appendMessages(new Message[]{message});
            store.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            log.info("Cannot send" + e.getCause().getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static Properties getSMTPProperties(String smtpHost) {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", smtpHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "20000");
        props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "20000");

        props.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", smtpHost);
        return props;
    }


    private static Message createMessage(Session session, String from, String[] recipients, String subject, String body)
            throws MessagingException {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
        message.addHeader("format", "flowed");
        message.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        Address[] addresses = new Address[recipients.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
            addresses[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
        }
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses);

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        return message;
    }
```

Here's the error

```
2020-05-06 08:55:51,601 INFO  [stdout] (default task-58) DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
2020-05-06 08:55:51,601 INFO  [stdout] (default task-58) DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
2020-05-06 08:55:51,601 INFO  [stdout] (default task-58) DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
2020-05-06 08:55:51,602 INFO  [stdout] (default task-58) DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
2020-05-06 08:55:51,602 INFO  [stdout] (default task-58) DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
2020-05-06 08:55:51,604 INFO  [stdout] (default task-58) DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
2020-05-06 08:55:51,608 INFO  [stdout] (default task-58) DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
2020-05-06 08:55:51,608 INFO  [stdout] (default task-58) DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=mail.dummy.local, user=wildfly, password=<null>
2020-05-06 08:55:51,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-58) DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
2020-05-06 08:55:51,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-58) DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.dummy.local", port 587, isSSL false
2020-05-06 08:56:21,627 ERROR [stderr] (default task-58) com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: mail.dummy.local, 587; timeout 30000;
2020-05-06 08:56:21,627 ERROR [stderr] (default task-58)   nested exception is:
2020-05-06 08:56:21,627 ERROR [stderr] (default task-58)    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

Comment: Do you have anything like application specific firewall or apparmor that could prevent the java vm from connecting to the server or port, while telnet works? I don't know about the AWS environment, but I found errors similar to this on other systems. Escpecially the java.net.SocketTimeoutException makes me think it is _not_ a wrong in-application-configuration or library version issue.

Comment: Yes, actually I don't have the access to aws instance .The guy who maintains server , told me he could telent from aws instance to mail server.
But after few hours of finding root cause with him again ,it turned out the problem was from his side. Thanks for the reply sir.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar issue and got it to work after downgrading to javax.mail:mail:1.4.5.

To give you more of a background, we had javax.mail 1.4.5 coming in from org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.3.2 and javax.mail 1.6 from javax:javaee-api:8.0

We had a module that worked with 1.4.5 so this was the only difference.

You could try this.

Comment: Yes,it turned out the problem was not from the code. Thanks for the reply .For using java mail dependency , https://stackoverflow.com/a/22021656/11547999 this gave me a clear understanding.