# Ensuring others can build my Java project solution and packages in IntelliJ

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea

I have a selenium java project I built using TestNG in IntelliJ.  When someone else clones my project from Github, they are unable to build the project due to missing dependencies.  I confirmed they have the dependencies listed in the pom.  They have tried to force reinstall of dependencies but it did not work.  I noticed there is an .idea folder in my solution that is not under source control. Does that matter?  What do i Need to make sure is under source control for others to clone and build my solution. Here is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ATT</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyCoach.POC.WebTests</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>MyCoach.POC.WebTests</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.141.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports-testng-adapter</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.16.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
      <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika</artifactId>
      <version>1.17</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
      <version>1.24.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/smtp -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>8.2.2.jre13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.imalittletester/thewaiter -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.imalittletester</groupId>
      <artifactId>thewaiter</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.141.59</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.stephenc.monte/monte-screen-recorder -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
      <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.7.0</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <parallel>all</parallel>
            <threadCount>2</threadCount>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
              <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
            <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you also add your pom file to the question.?

Comment: The .idea folder is for IntelliJ configuration files. You shouldn't need to add them into git.   Can you tell us which dependencies are missing?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020533/javamail-api-from-maven