# Batch file giving error when run it manually or by Jenkins

Tags: java, batch-file, jenkins

I am getting error when run batch file through Jenkins or manually by double click on it, **Error is :**

> [[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class
>   BulkMail.Send_Bulk_Mail - unable to resolve class reference
>   javax/mail/MessagingException Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.(TestNGClassFinder.java:59)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:153)     at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:522)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:111)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 18 more
>   Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

**Batch file Code :**

```
java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

**TestNG XML Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="BulkMail.Send_Bulk_Mail"/> 
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I tried almost every solution available on internet and SO , But still same error. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I don't know much about Java, but the error message is quite clear. See for example [How to resolve javax/mail/MessagingException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743031/how-to-resolve-javax-mail-messagingexception)

Comment: @Mofi - Sure Let me check.